# I want to start logging my air travels, will pilots accept to sign my log book?

Tags: air-travel

I want to start logging all my air travels in a personal log book, I will be registering flight no., route, date & time, aircraft registration, aircraft type, .etc, along with the captain's name and signature.

Is this possible? do pilots usually sign it or are there any restrictions?

Comment: Do you mean logging your time as crew, e.g. cabin staff? Or just as a passenger?

Comment: And a book?  Why not an online flight tracker like OpenFlights? http://openflights.org/

Comment: Ooh, I think you guys never heard of passengers log book.. The beauty of it is bring a book.. With signature of all captains you flew with.

Comment: Not overly fact based opinion only: I suspect that at very best it would be a matter of personal preference on the pilot's part. On perhaps a dozen occasions I have asked if I may visit the cockpit AFTER the flight and  on all such occasions I was allowed to AND on all occasions I was permitted to take photos - usually involving some or all of the flight crew. SO they are not averse to accommodating at least some specific customer requests. You'd not get access before or during flight. You may be able to "send up" the book via a cabin attendant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A commercial pilot friend believes that it'll come down to a few things:

1. Whether you as a passenger can get near the pilot. Some airlines won't let you near the cockpit, and prefer the pilots to stay in there until the passengers have disembarked. This'll make it trickier.
2. Possibly you could give it to a cabin crew member who could hand it to the pilot, but again it'll come down to company policy and also whether the cabin crew member wants to or not.
3. The pilot's discretion - even if the cabin crew member does, the pilot could be cranky or too busy and just plain refuses.

So that's the long answer - in summary, the short answer is "it depends".